# FuelUX Tree dataSource not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tree, fuelux

The documentation at http://getfuelux.com/javascript.html#tree doesn't give good example about how to use Javascript Datasource. I have read a lot of other questions on StackOverflow about it, but most of them are old (still use `name` instead of `text`). Can anyone help me with the `dataSource` and `callback` usage?

Here is my current code:

HTML:

```
<div class="row fuelux">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div id="grp-tree-hobby">
            <ul id="tree-hobbies" class="tree">
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    $("#tree-hobbies").tree({
        dataSource: function (parentData, callback) {
            console.log(parentData);
            callback({
                "data": [
                     { "text": "No hobby has been added yet", "type": 'item' },
                     { "text": "No hobby has been added yet", "type": 'item' },
                ],
            });
        },

    });

</script>
```

None exception is printed in the console, but the `ul` is still blank, and if I change `ul` into `div`, the result was still the same.

Can you please give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

This is [the code](https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/blob/gh-pages/assets/js/tree-examples.js) for the example on the actual docs page.

Where's the [rest of your markup](http://getfuelux.com/javascript.html#tree-examples) for the templating?

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. But I mean your html code is wrong. U must use this one:

```
        <ul class="tree tree-folder-select" role="tree" id="dirTree">
          <li class="tree-branch hide" data-template="treebranch" role="treeitem" aria-expanded="false">
            <div class="tree-branch-header">
              <button class="glyphicon icon-caret glyphicon-play"><span class="sr-only">Open</span></button>
              <button class="tree-branch-name">
                <span class="glyphicon icon-folder glyphicon-folder-close"></span>
                <span class="tree-label"></span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <ul class="tree-branch-children" role="group"></ul>
            <div class="tree-loader" role="alert">Loading...</div>
          </li>
          <li class="tree-item hide" data-template="treeitem" role="treeitem">
            <button class="tree-item-name">
              <span class="glyphicon icon-item fueluxicon-bullet"></span>
              <span class="tree-label"></span>
            </button>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

next I used this jquery definition:

```
$('#dirTree').tree({
    dataSource: function(options, callback){
        setTimeout(function () {
            callback({ data: [
                { name: 'Ascending and Descending', type: 'folder', dataAttributes: { id: 'F1' } },
                { name: 'Drawing Hands', type: 'folder', dataAttributes: { id: 'F2' } },
                { name: 'Belvedere', type: 'folder', dataAttributes: { id: 'F3' } },
                { name: 'House of Stairs', type: 'folder', dataAttributes: { id: 'F4' } },
                { name: 'Belvedere', type: 'folder', dataAttributes: { id: 'F5' } }
            ]});
        }, 400);},
    cacheItems: false,
    folderSelect: true,
    multiSelect: false
});
```

but not working :(